# Create Qml/C++ application as a plugin

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, plugins, qml

I wonder if it is possible to create an application as a plugin so it can be use inside another Gui application. Something like a media player with **Qml** in front (not widgets) inside a digital instrument cluster so that we can **load/unload** it whenever we need.
I know about shared objects and routine of making a c++ plugin.but I need GUI/qml apps as a plugin. Please let me know if it is possible and the steps required?

Thanks

Comment: plugin can also we written plug-in so it means you plug something in something else right ? so basically your question is a non-sense in itself

Comment: Plug into what? You could certainly have a DLL that launches a GUI when loaded, or changes an existing GUI.

Comment: [Plugins in Qt how-to](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html)

Comment: the major application is digital cluster instrument and there will be 4-5 application in it(navigation , player , phone etc). so i want the whole media app load when it is in use and unload it when no need for it. 
sorry for my bad English.@Cubic
@sandwood

Answer (score 1):

You can create your (**almost**) whole application as a plugin. **But** you will at some point need an executable to load your plugin.

But making your whole application as a plugin isn't the best way. Only use plugins for the parts of your application that you will change,  so that you only have to update the plugins file that are dynamically loaded, and let the rest stay static.

Now you also need to do some research by yourself, read the documentation, find out how to make and use a Qt plugin... Your question isn't specific and answers are not tutorials...

Comment: the major application is digital instrument cluster and inside it we have 4-5 application like media player , navigation , phone etc. for example we want the whole media player as plugin so we can load/unload it whenever it is in use. and the media player is designed with Qml/C++ so it is not just a c++shared object.

Comment: i see... just read the plugin documentation it's not very complicated